# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'...Getting dict out of two lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
list_keys= [A, A, B, C]
list_values= [1,2,3,4]
```

from these two lists, I want to create a dictionnary that uses elements of list_keys as keys and list_values as values while appending values to repetitive keyword:

```
final_dict = {A:[1, 2], B:3, C:4}
```

I tried:

```
from collections import defaultdict
final_dict = defaultdict(list)
list_keys= ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
list_values= [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(len(list_keys)):
    if list_keys[i] in final_dict:
        final_dict[list_keys[i]].append(list_values[i])
    else:
        final_dict[list_keys[i]] = list_values[i]
```

I'm getting this error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'"

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but in your `else` statement you were overwriting the default `list` with an integer making the subsequent `append` break.  See the change below.

Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
final_dict = defaultdict(list)
list_keys= ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
list_values= [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(len(list_keys)):
    if list_keys[i] in final_dict:
        final_dict[list_keys[i]].append(list_values[i])
    else:
        # Updated to use append versus assignment
        final_dict[list_keys[i]].append(list_values[i])

print(final_dict)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3], 'C': [4]})
```

Edit: By the way, the `if` `else` logic is unnecessary since you are appending to `final_dict` either way.

Example 2:

```
from collections import defaultdict
final_dict = defaultdict(list)
list_keys= ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
list_values= [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(len(list_keys)):
        final_dict[list_keys[i]].append(list_values[i])

print(final_dict)
```